# XSD elements, аналог атрибута OPTIONAL в DTD

Tags: xml, xsd

Доброго времени суток стаковцы. Возник такой вопрос, как в XSD схеме обозначить элемент `xs:element` (любой) параметром `required = false`, ибо есть несколько структур с присутствием того или иного элемента и его отсутствием? Или же, есть подобная структура ->

```
 <item_make_list>EMPTY</item_make_list>
 <corpse_make_list>EMPTY</corpse_make_list>

 <corpse_make_list>
    <item name="charcoal" min="1" max="1" chance="5.6617"/>
    <item name="magic_ring" min="1" max="1" chance="34.3131"/>
    <item name="rp_broad_sword" min="1" max="1" chance="4.5293"/>
 </corpse_make_list>
 <additional_make_list>EMPTY</additional_make_list>
 <additional_make_list>
   <group chance="70.0">
     <item name="adena" min="30" max="42" chance="100.0"/>
   </group>
   <group chance="25.7009">
     <item name="apprentice's_earing" min="1" max="1" chance="30.9859"/>
     <item name="necklace_of_magic" min="1" max="1" chance="23.0047"/>
     <item name="magic_ring" min="1" max="1" chance="46.0094"/>
   </group>
   <group chance="6.6988">
     <item name="stem" min="1" max="1" chance="29.1262"/>
     <item name="varnish" min="1" max="1" chance="14.5631"/>
     <item name="suede" min="1" max="1" chance="9.7087"/>
     <item name="silver_nugget" min="1" max="1" chance="5.8252"/>
     <item name="thread" min="1" max="1" chance="29.1262"/>
     <item name="rp_bow" min="1" max="1" chance="11.6506"/>
   </group>
 </additional_make_list>
```

Тогда как правильно инициализировать элемент с параметром "EMPTY", и дополнительно атрибуты при отсутствии этого параметра

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Было найдено альтернативное решение введением нового параметра `boolean` в конструктор элемента и инициализация атрибутов с типом `required=false`.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно указать минимальное число вхождений элемента - 0 (по умолчанию оно равно 1)

```
<xsd:element name="..." type ="..." minOccurs="0" />
```

Также у элемента `xsd:element` есть атрибут `maxOccurs` который задает максимальное число вхождений. По умолчанию оно также равно 1. Если максимальное число вхождений не ограничено, то этому атрибуту следует задать значение `unbounded`

Comment: В корне не то, что нужно

Comment: @GenCloud Судя по Вашему вопросу, Вам нужно указать элемент как необязательный. Я показал как это сделать. Если же Вам нужно что-то другое, то переформулируйте вопрос